# How can I generate a pdf with iReport using Arial Narrow font?

Tags: jasper-reports

I´m trying to develop a report with `Arial Narrow` font with `12 size`.

When I try to preview and generate a PDF, It didn´t come with the correct font.

I use:

- `Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.0 (Eclipse Version)`
- `Ubuntu 15.10`
- `Java 7`

What I need to do, to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I´m going to make as you have told.

Comment: I´m goint to try what they told above.

Comment: If you have trouble with font-extensions, pass a new question with the font-extensions you create, the jrxml, the font ecc...

Comment: @PetterFriberg It worked, strange because before I had a jar with the fonts but didn´t worked. I associated the font in Eclipse and also generated the jar.